# How to create a multiIndex object from series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data series 'rpt_date' :

```
>>> rpt_date
STK_ID
000002    [u'20060331', u'20060630']
000005    [u'20061231', u'20070331', u'20070630']
>>> type(rpt_date)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>
```

And how to create a multiIndex object (pandas.core.index.MultiIndex) by:

```
'my_index = gen_index_by_series (rpt_date)'
```

`'my_index'` looks like :

```
>>> my_index
MultiIndex
[('000002', '20060331') ('000002', '20060630') ('000005', '20061231')
 ('000005', '20070331') ('000005', '20070630')]
>>> type(my_index)
<class 'pandas.core.index.MultiIndex'>
>>>
```

So how to write `'gen_index_by_series(series)'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate the first element to the other you can use `itertools.repeat` and `zip`, in this way:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> L = [['000002', [u'20060331', u'20060630']],
...      ['000005', [u'20061231', u'20070331', u'20070630']]]
>>> couples = [zip(it.repeat(key), rest) for key, rest in L]
>>> couples
[[('000002', u'20060331'), ('000002', u'20060630')],
[('000005', u'20061231'), ('000005', u'20070331'), ('000005', u'20070630')]]
```

It shouldn't be too hard to obtain a list like `L` from the `Series` object.

To create a `MultiIndex` I belive you've to use the `from_tuples` method:

```
MultiIndex.from_tuples(sum(couples, []), names=('first', 'second'))
```

Since I'm not a pandas user I can't help much in the remaining tasks, even though they are probably easy. It's a matter of iterating over the Series in the correct way.

Comment: i try it. it works. Thanks. But the speed is not fast, and not 'vectorized'. Is there any other more vectorized method or any Pandas magic function ?

Comment: The original way the data is stored (as a Series of lists) is very inefficient (since getting the data out requires expensive iteration / unboxing of the values). Is there any way for you to change it?

Comment: 'rpt_date' is from 'rpt_date = ori_rpt.groupby('STK_ID').RPT_Date.apply(__makeup_rpt_date_list__)' . I have a 'ori_rpt' dataframe contains accumulative
financial report data which lost some date's report, '__makeup_rpt_date_list__' is used to make up the date list accordingly. And then build a multilevel index object 'full_rpt_idx', and 'rpt =  ori_rpt.reindex(index = full_rpt_idx)' to fill the missing data (although all the columns are NaN). Then I can safely use 'rpt - rpt.shift(1)' to get the quarterly data. YES, above staff is sluggish, but i can't find a more Pandas-way to improve it.